# Espresso, how to check an item from RecyclerView consists of certain layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

Hi my grid recycler view's 0th item should be always camera and
other items should be always video contents.

To check 0th item has layout of com.xx.yy.R.layout.item_camera
I tried like this:

> onView(withRecyclerView(recyclerViewResId).atPosition(0)).check(matches(withId(com.xx.yy.R.layout.item_camera)))

But it doesn't work, someone knows what I miss?

This is helper class:

```
fun withRecyclerView(recyclerViewId: Int) = RecyclerViewTestHelper.RecyclerViewMatcher(recyclerViewId)

object RecyclerViewTestHelper {

    class RecyclerViewMatcher(private val recyclerViewId: Int) {

        fun atPosition(position: Int): Matcher<View> {
            return atPositionOnView(position, -1)
        }

        fun atPositionOnView(position: Int, targetViewId: Int): Matcher<View> {

            return object : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
                var resources: Resources? = null
                var childView: View? = null

                override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
                    var idDescription = Integer.toString(recyclerViewId)
                    if (this.resources != null) {
                        try {
                            idDescription = this.resources!!.getResourceName(recyclerViewId)
                        } catch (var4: Resources.NotFoundException) {
                            idDescription = String.format("%s (resource name not found)",
                                    *arrayOf<Any>(Integer.valueOf(recyclerViewId)))
                        }

                    }

                    description.appendText("with id: $idDescription")
                }

                override fun matchesSafely(view: View): Boolean {

                    this.resources = view.getResources()

                    if (childView == null) {
                        val recyclerView = view.getRootView().findViewById(recyclerViewId) as RecyclerView
                        if (recyclerView != null && recyclerView!!.getId() === recyclerViewId) {
                            childView = recyclerView!!.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView
                        } else {
                            return false
                        }
                    }

                    if (targetViewId == -1) {
                        return view === childView
                    } else {
                        val targetView = childView!!.findViewById<View>(targetViewId)
                        return view === targetView
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        fun withResourceId(position: Int, targetViewId: Int): Matcher<View> {

            return object : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
                var resources: Resources? = null
                var childView: View? = null

                override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
                    var idDescription = Integer.toString(recyclerViewId)
                    if (this.resources != null) {
                        try {
                            idDescription = this.resources!!.getResourceName(recyclerViewId)
                        } catch (var4: Resources.NotFoundException) {
                            idDescription = String.format("%s (resource name not found)",
                                    *arrayOf<Any>(Integer.valueOf(recyclerViewId)))
                        }

                    }

                    description.appendText("with id: $idDescription")
                }

                override fun matchesSafely(view: View): Boolean {

                    this.resources = view.getResources()

                    if (childView == null) {
                        val recyclerView = view.getRootView().findViewById(recyclerViewId) as RecyclerView
                        if (recyclerView != null && recyclerView!!.getId() === recyclerViewId) {
                            childView = recyclerView!!.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position).itemView
                        } else {
                            return false
                        }
                    }

                    if (targetViewId == -1) {
                        return view === childView
                    } else {
                        val targetView = childView!!.findViewById<View>(targetViewId)
                        return view === targetView
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CustomAssertions {
        companion object {
            fun hasItemCount(count: Int): ViewAssertion {
                return RecyclerViewItemCountAssertion(count)
            }
        }

        private class RecyclerViewItemCountAssertion(private val count: Int) : ViewAssertion {

            override fun check(view: View, noViewFoundException: NoMatchingViewException?) {
                if (noViewFoundException != null) {
                    throw noViewFoundException
                }

                if (view !is RecyclerView) {
                    throw IllegalStateException("The asserted view is not RecyclerView")
                }

                if (view.adapter == null) {
                    throw IllegalStateException("No adapter is assigned to RecyclerView")
                }
                ViewMatchers.assertThat("RecyclerView item count", view.adapter.itemCount, CoreMatchers.equalTo(count))
            }
        }
    }

    class HintTextColorMatcher private constructor(private val color: Int) : BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView::class.java) {
        override fun matchesSafely(item: TextView): Boolean {
            return item.currentHintTextColor == color
        }

        override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
            description.appendText("with hint text color:")
                    .appendValue(color)
        }

        companion object {
            fun withHintTextColor(color: Int): HintTextColorMatcher {
                return HintTextColorMatcher(color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error log:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'with id: 2131427448' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with id: jp.naver.line.android.beta:layout/media_content_item
Got: "RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=477, height=476, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=964.0, y=3.0, child-count=10}"

at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1566)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
at gallery.android.line.naver.jp.line_android_gallery.RobotActions.BaseActions.checkRecyclerViewItemRes(BaseActions.kt:46)
at gallery.android.line.naver.jp.line_android_gallery.RobotActions.PickerActivityActions.clickFirstMediaItem(PickerActivityActions.kt:42)
at gallery.android.line.naver.jp.line_android_gallery.GalleryInstruTest$launchPickerForAllTest$2.invoke(GalleryInstruTest.kt:76)
at gallery.android.line.naver.jp.line_android_gallery.GalleryInstruTest$launchPickerForAllTest$2.invoke(GalleryInstruTest.kt:20)
at gallery.android.line.naver.jp.line_android_gallery.RobotActions.PickerActivityActionsKt.picker(PickerActivityActions.kt:9)
at gallery.android.line.naver.jp.line_android_gallery.GalleryInstruTest.launchPickerForAllTest(GalleryInstruTest.kt:72)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1939)
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 'with id: 2131427448' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: with id: jp.naver.line.android.beta:layout/media_content_item
Got: "RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=477, height=476, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=964.0, y=3.0, child-count=10}"

at android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.assertThat(ViewMatchers.java:1053)
at android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions$2.check(ViewAssertions.java:89)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.run(ViewInteraction.java:170)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Comment: Could you post the error?

Comment: @Aaron I added error log

Answer (score 0):

I think here's the problem:

```
onView(withRecyclerView(recyclerViewResId).atPosition(0))
        .check(matches(withId(com.xx.yy.R.layout.item_camera)))
```

You're trying to match an id with a layout, which of course is incorrect. You can only use a resource id on `withId`, not others.